# My Flutter app keep freezing when I use image url value

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'd like to ask about how to fix this. Whenever I use URL value, my app will just freeze forever. Not even show an exception. Anyways, when I put directly URL, it work normally. It actually happen to every parts of my app. But mainly place I used is here.

This work

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: Uri.encodeFull('https://i.imgur.com/Fr8WH7d.jpg'),
  width: 150,
  height: 112,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
 )
```

This one not (same value)

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: Uri.encodeFull(widget.uri),
  width: 150,
  height: 112,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
 )
```

Here is full code if anyone want.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

class DefListView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String des;
  final String price;
  final String uri;

  DefListView(
      {required this.title,
      required this.des,
      required this.price,
      required this.uri});

  @override
  _DefListViewState createState() => _DefListViewState();
}

class _DefListViewState extends State<DefListView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 10),
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width,
        height: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 3,
              color: Color(0x411D2429),
              offset: Offset(0, 1),
            )
          ],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(8, 8, 8, 8),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 1, 1, 1),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl: Uri.encodeFull(widget.uri),
                    width: 150,
                    height: 112,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(8, 8, 4, 0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        widget.title,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 4, 8, 0),
                          child: Text(widget.des,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                              )),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 4, 0, 0),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.chevron_right_rounded,
                      color: Color(0xFF57636C),
                      size: 24,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 0, 4, 8),
                    child: Text(
                      widget.price,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

1.I've tried flutter doctor and flutter clean as well.
2.Changing to Image.Network() doesn't work.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using [Uri.encodeFull](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/encodeFull.html) ? From the url you using it would make more sense to use [Uri.parse](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/parse.html)

Comment: I think it happened when I tried to solve this problem. So it actually no difference between using it or not.
About Uri.parse. There are errors that occurred due to the wrong parameter data type.